# how to make Powershell output file path using mapped drive path instead of true path?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

How can I change the path in result using mapped drive instead of true path? Now I got something like `\\server\data\work\....` I would like to see it in lets say `K:\work\....`
I can't use mapped drive path for variable because it does not work with task scheduler....

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source -Filter *.prt | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)} | sort LastWriteTime -descending | select name,LastWriteTime,Directory | convertto-html -head $a -body "<H2>FILES LIST FOR PAST 7 DAYS</H2>" | out-file $output\result.htm
```

Comment: Please provide more context. Why/how do you get a UNC path when you already have a mapped drive?

Comment: Because I need to setup this as a scheduled task as admin, and task scheduler wont work with mapped path in powershell somehow....

Comment: What's wrong with using the true UNC path? That should work anywhere. (Also going one way is simple - each mapped drive points to one UNC path, but going the other way is not simple - one UNC path could be pointed to by many mapped drive letters).

Comment: Nothing wrong with using UNC path...the results are for Users not for admins, users dont need to know which server holding there data, they only need to know mapped drive letter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapped drive letter should work as long as you're running the Powershell script as a user who has the drive mapped. Otherwise, you need to use [New-PSDrive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx) to map the drive for the session.

```
New-PSDrive –Name K –PSProvider FileSystem –Root "\\server\data"
```

Comment: Sorry, i tried your way, but got an error `New-PSDrive : A drive with the name 'K' already exists.` and script wont run... I tried to use K:\ and run script directly, the result still true path. and i scheduled it to run with K:\, no result at all....

Comment: So it errors on the K drive existing when run as a scheduled task, but runs fine manually under the same credentials?

Comment: yes, run it manually, got error, run it as a scheduled task, also shows error in log, run it manually  with K:\ still results in true path, run it as scheduled task with K:\ results nothing, an empty page....

Comment: In testing, your script works when run as a user with access to the specified mapped drive, using the drive letter, as a scheduled task. Are you *sure* that you're testing the script under the same credentials as the task?

Comment: YES, All my task are performed under admin account

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a PSDrive at the start of your script. Make sure that the account running the script(through task scheduler) has the required rights on the share.

```
New-PSDrive –Name "K" –PSProvider FileSystem –Root "\\server\data"
#.... something something, creating $output variable etc. 
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $source -Filter *.prt | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)} | sort LastWriteTime -descending | select name,LastWriteTime,Directory | convertto-html -head $a -body "<H2>FILES LIST FOR PAST 7 DAYS</H2>" | out-file $output\result.htm
```